# Design pattern to read a record and determine what type of record it is?

Tags: java, design-patterns

For example a csv file contains credit card records and I want to determine what type of credit card it is? I am confused between Strategy and Template Design Patterns

Comment: forgot about design pattern that fits you, think about solution how you want to do it and then apply right pattern which fits your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Credit card types are fairly limited, there are only so many standard credit cards. If you're trying to determine what type of credit card it is, one approach would be to use an interface to represent the credit card and then a enum to represent the likely finite number of cards.

```java
public interface CreditCard {

}
```

```java
enum StandardCreditCard implements CreditCard {
    MASTERCARD,

    AMERICAN_EXPRESS,

    BANK_OF_AMERICA
}
```

The positives to this approach is that it's quick and dirty. Enums by default use the multiton pattern. Each element is of type CreditCard, but you can still add more credit cards in the future if you need to.

```java
interface MyOtherCreditCard extends CreditCard {

}
```